# I want to try loading images in a div element and then perform another function if this fails after preset 5 seconds using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please I really need help on this.
I have series of images on a site and I want to display a modal when a picture is selected.

The problem is that I don't want to display a picture that is not fully loaded(i.e with the alt attribute value) so I want to try loading the image first for 5 seconds and if it's still not fully loaded after 5 seconds, I will just go ahead to displaying the not-fully-loaded image.

Check out the commented algorithm below. Thank you.

```
// Hide Modal div By Default till preview button Is Clicked
// If Preview Button Is Clicked And All Images Are Fully Loaded Before 5 Seconds ElApses
// Show Modal And Display Fully Loaded Images
// Else If 5 SecondS Elapses And Not All Images Are Fully Loaded
// Show Modal And Display Not-fully-loaded Images alongside Fully Loaded Ones If Any
```

```
<!Doctype Html>
<html Lang="En">

    <head>
        <title> Preview Images </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="previewContainer">
            <img src="image1.jpg">
            <img src="image2.jpg">
            <img src="image3.jpg">
            <img src="image4.jpg">
        </div>

        <button id="previewImages">Preview Images</button>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //  Hides preview div on page load till triggered
            $('#previewContainer').hide();

            //  When preview is initiated on button click
            $('#previewImages').click(function() {
                //  Initializes count of all img tags in preview element
                var imgCount = 0;   
                //  Gets count of all img tags
                var allImg = $('#previewContainer img').length;

                //  If images in preview div are loaded
                $('#previewContainer img').load(function() {

                    //  Increment imgCount variable as more images loads
                    imgCount++;             

                    //  Confirm if all images are loaded
                    if (imgCount == total_imgCount) {                   
                        $('#previewContainer').show();
                    } else {    //  If all images are not loaded, delay for 5 seconds and then show preview
                        $('#previewContainer').delay(5000).queue(function() {
                            $(this).show();
                            $(this).dequeue();
                        });
                    }

                });

            });

        });

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use the [`error()`](https://api.jquery.com/error/) event handler to hide the image if the image loading fails. If you want more specific help, then we need to see your code.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted? You said what you want and showed some code, but you didn't explain what your problem or question is with that code.

Comment: Well, the code was constantly firing the "else" part of it and completely ignoring the "if" part. I couldn't understand how the .load() method was handling the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found this to be working and I'm just wondering if there are any exceptions where this would work or UA issues of any sort.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            // Hides element on page load
            $("#div").hide();


            // Loads images and gets div element ready for display with selected time delay
            function loadPreview() {

                // Longest trial period
                var time = 5000;
            // Initialize loaded images count to 0
            var img = 0;

                // Appends images to hidden div element. Could be data from an AJAX request
                $("#div").append('<img src="Images/Logo/vxTrminal.png" width="100%" alt="" class=""><img src="Images/Logo/vxTerminal.png" width="100%" alt="" class=""><img src="Images/Logo/vxTerminal.png" width="100%" alt="" class=""><img src="Images/Logo/vxTerminal.png" width="100%" alt="" class=""><img src="Images/Logo/vxTerminal.png" width="100%" alt="" class="">');
                // Gets total length of images in div element
                var tot = $("#div img").length;

                // Checks if images are loaded
                $("#div img").load(function(){
                    // Increments images count as each image loads
                    img++;

                    // If all images have been loaded
                    if (img == tot) {
                        // Reset delay to show preview images immediately
                        time = 0;
                    }

                    // Calls function to perform images previwe with selected time delay
                    var G = setTimeout(showPreview,time);

                });

            }

            // Runs loadPreview function
            loadPreview();

            // Shows div element after selected time delay
            function showPreview() {
                $("#div").show();
            }


        });
```

What the code above does is that if any of the img elements has a broken or unavailable value in its src attribute, the loadPreview function waits for a maximum time delay of 5 seconds to ensure the images can't really be loaded before calling showPreview function.

On the other hand, once all the src attribute values of all the img elements are found and loaded, loadPreview calls showPreview function with 0 delay.